# Estimating $\sum n^{-1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

Could someone please explain me how does one obtain the following estimate:
$$
\sum_{n \leq X} n^{-1/2} = \frac12 X^{1/2} + c + O(X^{-1/2}),
$$
where $c$ is some constant.

Thank you very much!

PS As pointed out in the comments, $1/2$ in front of $X^{1/2}$ is a typo... I would like an answer with the correct coefficient here.

Comment: Have you tried Stieltjes integration?

Comment: **Hint** Since the summand is a decreasing function of $n$, bound the sum by left and right endpoint Riemann sums.

Comment: I'm afraid there's something I don't understand: the sum is certainly larger than $X^{-1/2}\times X=X^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Aretino You are right... it must be a typo in the book I am reading...

Comment: The full asymptotic expansion can be found in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/670202/59379). $$2\sqrt{n} + \zeta(1/2) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}
-1/24\,{n}^{-3/2}+{\frac {1}{384}}\,{n}^{-7/2}-{\frac {1}{1024}}\,{n}^
{-11/2}+{\frac {143}{163840}}\,{n}^{-15/2}\\-{\frac {1105}{786432}}\,{n}
^{-19/2}+{\frac {223193}{62914560}}\,{n}^{-23/2}-{\frac {1300075}{
100663296}}\,{n}^{-{\frac {27}{2}}}+{\frac {137514723}{2147483648}}\,{
n}^{-{\frac {31}{2}}} + \cdots$$

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422559/what-is-sum-limits-i-1n-sqrt-i

Comment: @achillehui: Euler Mc Laurin Summation gives that, and more (except for $\zeta(1/2)$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Euler McLaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) which gives us the estimate

$$ 2 \sqrt{n} + K + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-3/2})$$

It can be shown by other means that $K = \zeta(\frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 7):

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)^2}$$
hence the claim follows just by creative telescoping/ [the Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), but the first term of the asymptotics should be $\color{red}{2}\cdot\,X^{1/2}$. In such a case, $c=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this neat answer! Would it be possible that I get a little more detail by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

Denote $f(x)=x^{-1/2}, \ S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)$. Using the mean value theorem we obtain that $f(x)=f(k)+(x-k)f'(x_k)$, for $x\in[k,k+1]$ where $x_k\in(k,k+1)$, thus 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx-S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k}^{k+1}(f(x)-f(k))dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k}^{k+1}(x-k)f'(x_k)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^nf'(x_k).
\end{align*}
Since
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx=2n^{1/2}-2
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\Big|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f'(x_k)\Big|\leq\int_{n}^{\infty}|f'(x)|dx= f(n)=n^{-1/2}
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
S_n=2n^{1/2}-2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f'(x_k)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f'(x_k)=2n^{1/2}+c+O(n^{-1/2}).
\end{align*}
Comment: to get better expression for c use Taylor formula of second order: $f(x)=f(k)+(x-k)f'(k)+(x-k)^2/2f''(k)$.