# Reference for finite sum of $k^{\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/422636/161591), we are given a great formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{\alpha}$ for all real alpha. For a paper I'm writing, I need a reference for a textbook or a paper which contains this result and its proof.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just cite the answer you linked? (via the "cite" button at the bottom to get Bibtex).

Comment: Is it academically viable?

Comment: It has been done before, in respectable papers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the formula the OP proves is also known as [Faulhaber's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), which is a result of the [Euler-Maclaurin Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). So, as they are "classical" this is how I'd write and cite them in a paper.