# Asymptotic behaviour of Schatten $p$-norm

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, harmonic-numbers, singular-values

Consider the following matrix

$$\Gamma(4) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0\\
0 & -\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{3}\\
0 & 0 & -\sqrt{3} &0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So it's easy to understand the form of $\Gamma(n)$: it is skew-symmetric, with two diagonal lines with entries {$\pm\sqrt{1}, \pm\sqrt{2},\dots, \pm\sqrt{n}$}. My question is how to get the large $n$ behavior for the summation of powers of its singular values:

$$\sum_i \sigma_i ^p$$

The above expression is also related to Schatten p-norm. For example, it's not difficult to show that

$$ \sum_i \sigma_i^2 = \|\Gamma(n)\|_2^2 \sim n^2/2 $$

However, I also need to know the large $n$ behaviour for $p=1,4$. I wrote a small code to do a fitting which suggests that

$$ \sum_i \sigma_i \sim n^{3/2} $$

and

$$ \sum_i \sigma_i^4 \sim n^{3} $$

Any idea how to prove them? It seems like the asympotic behavior is the same as the summation of the matrix entries (see [What is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt i\ $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422559/what-is-sum-limits-i-1n-sqrt-i))

$$\sum_i (\sqrt{i})^p$$